# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch error while creating google login through django

Tags: python, django

I have been going through django by example book.I have made the necessary changes for google login.

below image shows https://console.developers.google.com/apis setting.
[image: Below is the authorized redirect URI settings]

Changes for keys in settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
                    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                    'account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend',
                    'social.backends.facebook.Facebook2OAuth2',#for face book authentication
                    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
                    )





#Creating a facebook authentication for django auth framework
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '356920068048038' # Facebook App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'f57792e060753abb7f15ed183512ee4a' # Facebook App Secret


#Asking additional permissions for facebook users
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']


SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True



#google authentication
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY ='419087081878-rt976l4dovnujv6lhjnfgtkc8sejpjlf.apps.googleusercontent.com' # Google Consumer Key
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'ItMLE4-nSID-UG73xm7tiL2f' # Google Consumer Secret
```

I have enabled the google+API as mentioned in the book,below is my html link.

```
<li class="google"><a href="{% url "social:begin" "google-oauth2" %}">Login with Google</a></li>
```

When I click on login with google ,iam getting the error **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.**Below is the screenshot.

[image]

I have gone through various online resources to resolve this but not successful as of now,please let me know how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri that google shows in the error message differs from the authorized uri in the google settings. Add the localhost uri to google settings.

Comment: ,In the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file , I have mentioned 127.0.0.1 mysite.com,as mentioned in django by example book.Hence same uri is specified in google settings.

Comment: ,I have tried out localhost as well,but same error was displayed.

Comment: @Chandan did you wait after you added the localhost uri to the google settings? it takes some time before it is processed by google.

Comment: ,like how many minutes on an average i should wait so that it  will be processed by google  and since i have given mysite reference in hosts can i use the same as mentioned in this question